# JavaScript onMouseOver works on Chrome but not Desktop Safari

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I am currently developing a website where I wish an action to be performed when the user hovers over an item.

So far, this code works in both Chrome and Firefox but not Safari for macOS.

When searching for this issue, all results have been mentioning that iOS safari does not detect onMouseOver events. I understand this as you cannot hover when touching. However, on the desktop side (macOS), I would expect it to work. For now, the onMouseHover is only executed when the user clicks on it. This is what I would expect an onClick event to do.

How would I get my onHover code to work with macOS Safari?

**Here is an example of my code**:

```
<div onMouseOver="myFunc(this)">
    <!-- Other HTML code here -->
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunc(element){
      //Do stuff
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Don't know why but 10mins later, exact same code without a refresh and it works. Seems like Safari was bugging out.

Comment: have you tried `onmouseover="myFunc(this)"` with lower case? Upper/upper camel case for tags and attributes is deprecated for a long time now.

Comment: Please close this question or delete it as I think it was a bug with Safari and therefor is no longer a real question. I cannot delete it as someone has answered.

Comment: @DimitriL. Just found out it was a temporary issue with Safari.

Comment: typically mouseover is supported on ios, it depends on how you implement it: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

Use lowercase:

```
// change this
<div onMouseOver="myFunc(this)">
// to this
<div onmouseover="myFunc(this)">
```